# Display image with border on centered page

Tags: css, image, position, border, scaling

I'm trying to display an image centered on a page with a border that should have different paddings and margins on it's side. The images will be of different widhts and heights. So I need it to stretch accordingly.

I put this in the body to remove all margins:

```
body {
    margin:0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
```

Then I used this to put the border around the image.

```
#imgcontainer {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

But then the border stretches all across the with of the page. Is there any way to prevent his? If I put:

```
position:relative;
```

The border snaps into place but then the image is not centered anymore.

If I put a container box around #imgcontainer it also snaps to the edge of the page.

I think it can be solved simply with some combo of position:relative/absolute?

This is what I'm talking about: http://kareldc.com/dislexicon/1-motion.html

Thx!

Comment: add html code pls.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now define according to @Fabrizo Calderan

css as like this

```
#imgcontainer {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top; 
}
```

than your result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood the problem you could assign `display: inline-block` to `#imgcontainer`, otherwise post a fiddle showing the issue

Comment: have you tried to apply my suggest? Is it the desired effect?

Comment: Yes, then the #imgcontainer snaps to the top. http://www.kareldc.com/dislexicon/1-motion2.html

Comment: sorry, but is not yet clear what do you exactly want to obtain: do you want to center both horizontally and vertically the container?

Comment: With vertical-align:top; it seemed to work. Thanks! @Rohit Azad

Answer (score 0):

you can just apply the border effect to the img tag alone.

for example, just put

```
#imgcontainer img { 
      border-color: red;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for you: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QKcTb/)